# How to stop running async function on node.js from react application?

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, sockets, socket.io

React app can run node.js function which preparing data and sending information to the database in batches.
It takes a lot of time and I would like to add the ability to stop this function right from react app.

```
const getShopifyOrders = require('./shopify');
const getTrack = require('./tracking');
const Order = require('./model');

async function addOrdersToDB(limit) {
  try {
    // Get latest order from DB
    let latestOrd = await Order.findOne().sort('-order_number');

    do {
      // Get Shopify Orders
      let orders = await getShopifyOrders(
        latestOrd ? latestOrd.order_id : 0,
        limit
      );
      latestOrd = orders[0] ? orders[orders.length - 1] : undefined;

      // Update array with tracking status
      let fullArray = await getTrack(orders);

      // Add to DB
      let ins = await Order.insertMany(fullArray, { ordered: false });
      console.log(`Added ${ins.length} entries`);
    } while (latestOrd);
  } catch (err) {
    console.log(err);
  }
}
module.exports = addOrdersToDB;
```

I tried a lot of things to include in this function including:

- while loop: added the variable outside the function - if 'true' - run code, if not - return - it just doesn't work (variable was changed from react using socket.IO)
- setTimeout (also setInterval), triger clearTimeout function from react: this doesn't work as setTimeout and setInterval doesn't work in async function

after that:

- made (actually fond here on stackoverflow) new function to promisify setTimeout to be able to use in async function:

```
const setTimeout2 = (callback, ms) => {
  return new Promise(
    resolve =>
      (to = setTimeout(() => {
        callback();
        resolve();
      }, ms))
  );
};
```

```
async function addOrdersToDB(limit) {
  do {
    await setTimeout2(async () => {
      try {
        // some code here
      } catch (err) {
        console.log(err);
      }
    }, 400);
  } while (latestOrderExist);
}
```

```
function clearTO() {
  setTimeout(() => {
    console.log('clearTO');
    clearTimeout(to);
  }, 3000);
}
```

This for some reason doesn't iterate.

Is there solution for this?
Thanks!

Comment: Can you show code for a real problem you're trying to solve.  There is no GENERIC way to stop an asynchronous operation in nodejs.  Every type of asynchronous operation is different.  For example, you can stop `setTimeout()` by calling `clearTimeout(timerid)`, but there is no means of stopping `fs.readFile()`.  So, it entirely depends upon the asynchronous operation, thus we need to see real code with a real problem you're trying to solve.

Comment: Please post questions with your actual real code.  For some unknown reasons, people think it is better to make up pseudo-code and ask some sort of generic question.  That is pretty much never the best way to get a good answer to your problem.  For starters, we can only see the actual and real problem when we can see your actual code and in addition, when we can see your real code, we can sometimes offer you better solutions than you even thought of to ask about.  Plus, when you distill it down to pseudo-code, people usually leave out important details of the problem.

Comment: Just added node.js code. Thank!

Comment: In your real code, what are you trying to abort from the outside?  Are you trying to abort the `do/while` loop in your first code block?

Comment: Yes, I tried to abort do/while loop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To abort the `do/while` loop, you will need to add an additional test to that loop that is some variable that can be modified from the outside world.  Also, note that the additional test only works here because you're using `await` inside the loop.  If there was no `await` inside the loop, then the loop would be entirely synchronous and there would be no ability to change a variable from outside the loop while the loop was running (because of nodejs' single-threadedness).

Since this is a server (and globals are generally bad), I will assume we should not use a global.  So instead, I would restructure `addOrdersToDB()` to return a data structure that contains both the promise the existing version returns and an `abort()` function the caller can call to stop the current processing.  This also permits multiple separate calls to `addOrdersToDB()` to be running, each with their own separate `abort()` method.

```
function addOrdersToDB(limit) {
    let stop = false;

    function abort() {
        stop = true;
    }

    async function run() {
        try {
            // Get latest order from DB
            let latestOrd = await Order.findOne().sort('-order_number');

            do {
                // Get Shopify Orders
                let orders = await getShopifyOrders(
                    latestOrd ? latestOrd.order_id : 0,
                    limit
                );
                latestOrd = orders[0] ? orders[orders.length - 1] : undefined;

                // Update array with tracking status
                let fullArray = await getTrack(orders);

                // Add to DB
                let ins = await Order.insertMany(fullArray, { ordered: false });
                console.log(`Added ${ins.length} entries`);
            } while (!stop && latestOrd);

            // make resolved value be a boolean that indicates
            // whether processing was stopped with more work still pending
            return !!(latestOrd && stop);

        } catch (err) {
            // log error and rethrow so caller gets error propagation
            console.log(err);
            throw err;
        }
    }
    return {
        promise: run(),
        abort: abort
    }
}
```

So, to use this, you would have to change the way you call `addOrdersToDB()` (since it no longer returns just a promise) and you would have to capture the `abort()` function that it returns.  Then, some other part of your code can call the `abort()` function and it will then flip the internal `stop` variable that will cause your `do/while` loop to stop any further iterations.

Note, this does not stop the asynchronous processing inside the current iteration of the `do/while` loop - it just stops any further iterations of the loop.

Note, I also changed your `catch` block so that it rethrows the error so that the caller will see if/when there was an error.

And, the resolved value of the function is the internal `stop` variable so the caller can see if the loop was aborted or not.  A `true` resolved value means the loop was aborted and there was more work to do.

---

Here's an additional version of the function that creates more opportunities for it to stop between `await` operations within your function and within the loop.  This still does not abort an individual database operation that may be in progress - you'd have to examine whether your database supports such an operation and, if so, how to use it.

```
function addOrdersToDB(limit) {
    let stop = false;

    function abort() {
        stop = true;
    }

    async function run() {
        try {
            // Get latest order from DB
            let latestOrd = await Order.findOne().sort('-order_number');

            if (!stop) {
                do {
                    // Get Shopify Orders
                    let orders = await getShopifyOrders(
                        latestOrd ? latestOrd.order_id : 0,
                        limit
                    );
                    latestOrd = orders[0] ? orders[orders.length - 1] : undefined;
                    if (stop) break;

                    // Update array with tracking status
                    let fullArray = await getTrack(orders);
                    if (stop) break;

                    // Add to DB
                    let ins = await Order.insertMany(fullArray, { ordered: false });
                    console.log(`Added ${ins.length} entries`);
                } while (!stop && latestOrd);
            }

            // make resolved value be a boolean that indicates
            // whether processing was stopped with more work still pending
            return !!(latestOrd && stop);

        } catch (err) {
            // log and rethrow error so error gets propagated back to cller
            console.log(err);
            throw err;
        }
    }
    return {
        promise: run(),
        abort: abort
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you!! For some reason, it shows 'E11000 duplicate key error collection: tracking.orders index: order_number_1 dup key' when run abort function. But now I know which direction to go.

Comment: You said: it does not stop the asynchronous processing inside the current iteration of the do/while loop. Is it possible to stop this asynchronous process?

Comment: @NeoN - What exactly do you want to stop?  You can add an additional check for the `stop` variable between each of your `await` statements and abort in between them (I can add that to the answer).  If you want to abort an actual running database operation, that would be specific to your database as to whether that is possible or not.

Comment: @NeoN - New version added to my answer that will also stop between database operations, not just at the end of a loop iteration.